# How to handle popup links in CefSharp Offscreen

Tags: c#, console-application, cefsharp

I write a console application that uses CEF offscreen rendering mode and provides its own windows in which the images returned from CEF render engine are presented.
I managed to get child windows to open (and close), but I have a problem with sites that have a "Connect with AccelAero" feature, like http://reservations.daallo.com/xbe/public/showLogin.action.
In such websites, a new window pops up allowing the user to enter his/her FB credentials. Then the popup closes and the website let you enter.
In my implementation the popup does appear, but once approved it stays open with no content (testing with the Dev-Tools shows it is no longer connected), and nothing happens in the parent window.

```
public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{     
    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        //var chromiumWebBrowser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)browserControl;
        //var windowX = (windowInfo.X == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.X;
        //var windowY = (windowInfo.Y == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Y;
        //var windowWidth = (windowInfo.Width == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Width;
        //var windowHeight = (windowInfo.Height == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Height;

        ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumBrowser = null;
        /*
           it is a website which have a scripts that start a new popup 
           on its first page and when I want to grab the handler of the 
           popup window in a new page the scripts of the page understand
           this and reopen a new popup window which I want to grab its 
           handler too.
        */
        chromiumBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(targetUrl);
        chromiumBrowser.SetAsPopup();
        chromiumBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = this;
        newBrowser = chromiumBrowser;
        return true; //Infinite loop
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
   browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://reservations.daallo.com/xbe/public/showLogin.action");
   browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();
```

Comment: What does your implementation of `ILifeSpanHandler` look like?

Comment: @ amaitland I implemented ILifeSpanHandler, but I cannot handle the new window popup as Offscreen.

Comment: Without code that demos your problem it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @amaitland Add implementation of ILifeSpanHandler

Comment: Possible that nobody has ever tried to create a popup using their own instance of `ChromiumWebBrowser`. You can probably get it working, possibly require debugging and code changes. Firstly don't create the underlying browser when creating a new `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance.

Comment: @amaitland it is a website which have a scripts that start a new popup on its first page and when I want to grab the handler of the popup window in a new page the scripts of the page understand this and reopen a new popup window which I want to grab its handler too,its outcome is a series of opened tab and finally application will crash

Comment: You'll have to debug implement that yourself

Comment: @amaitland I changed the text questions

Comment: As I said, debug it yourself, see what's going on. The scenario your trying is one that I've never tested, so it's quite possible it doesn't work.